# ExtJS5: Infinite Scroll in Tree Grid

Tags: extjs, infinite-scroll, extjs5, treegrid

Can we have a ExtJs5 **Tree Grid Panel** which provides below features:

1. Inifinite Scroll so that  rows are rendered with some limit on scroll and not all records at sametime.

   2. On Click of any root node of a particular row (could be 2/3 levels), i can fire a ajax call to populate a grid/form inside the expanded row.

Please provide your expert suggestions in this regard asap.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. yes you can use infinite scrolling for TreeGrid. Checkout the [example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/tree/buffer-rendered-treegrid.html)

2. If you want expand a row and inside that row you want a form or a grid, then I would say that is nearly impossible. You can only handle this with a custom renderer for the gridpanel and even with this you must create it via Ext.create and render it into the treepanel.

Why dont use something like this: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l26

Comment: Thanks Simon for your reply!, however as i said , i want to generate the child nodes and load it with a grid (with some ajax call) ONLY wheni expand the row's root node and NOT pre-load the childrens ..hence stuck here :(.. any clues of :         1. How to connect to the row expand event ? 2.  How to insert the Grid thru Ext.Create() in the target node ?

Comment: So you want create a grid in a tree node after a node is expanded?

Comment: As I wrote this is nearly impossible and can only be realized with a great effort. Maybe you can split your view as I did in the fiddle?